# Deriving Zeeman energy from HdB

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

How to derive the Zeeman energy density $E=\mu_0 \mathbf{M}\cdot \mathbf{H}$ from the general expression $E=\int \mathbf{H}\cdot d\mathbf{B}$?

My try for a 1D case:
The Zeeman energy can be seen as the energy difference between the case when there is no magnetization $M=0$ and no field $H=0$ and the case where there is magnetization $M=M_0$ and field $H_0$. So, we get
\begin{align}
\Delta E &= \int\limits_{0}^{\mu_0(H_0+M_0)}  HdB \\
&= \int\limits_{0}^{\mu_0(H_0+M_0)} Hd(\mu_0(H+M))\\
&= \mu_0 \int\limits_{0}^{\mu_0(H_0+M_0)} Hd(H+M)\\
\end{align}

I cannot find how to further solve this integral... The final result should be $\Delta E=\mu_0 H_0M_0$ according to the Zeeman energy.

Comment: It is a volume integral. In addition, your expression for the Zeeman energy presuppose that the field and the magnetization are constant, hence the integral is trivial. Finally, one needs a thermodynamic transformation, making magnetization independent variable instead of the field.

Comment: Ah, I see, I actually also need to integrate the Zeeman energy. About the thermodynamic transformation, how does this work?